# How run compaction on using start and end token range

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I need to run compaction on a very large table, 40% of disk space is free, but compaction take for a long time and fill up 100% of the disk then Cassandra process goes down, so I decided to run compaction by start and end token range, I select the ranges:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> SELECT tokens FROM system.local;
 tokens
 {'-1086477467151825006', '-6979941880848102278', '-9077716633074993870', '4450419032446811241', '7953145647081579725', '945723047588545683'}
```

When I run the compact command by specifying the start and end token range, I'm getting the following error:

```
$nodetool repair -st -1091112185956497009 -et -1164785492893427439 main tbl_evetns

error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2021-06-02 22:57:42,499] Requested range (-1091112185956497009,-1164785492893427439] intersects a local range ((6717615618706114838,7883825036204854784]) but is not fully contained in one; this would lead to imprecise repair. keyspace: main
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2021-06-02 22:57:42,499] Requested range (-1091112185956497009,-1164785492893427439] intersects a local range ((6717615618706114838,7883825036204854784]) but is not fully contained in one; this would lead to imprecise repair. keyspace: main
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.progress(RepairRunner.java:116)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.progress.jmx.JMXNotificationProgressListener.handleNotification(JMXNotificationProgressListener.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `nodetool ring` to find what exact ranges are owned by specific node, and then issue corresponding repair command.

But in reality it's better to use the [Reaper tool](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) - it does the calculations automatically, split owned ranges into sub-ranges, etc.

Comment: I used nodetool repair and nodetool ring to find the token ranges, but the ranges are not quite match, also I checked repear, I couldn't find where exactly I can see the split of ranges,  only can see in "view segments" button, start and end ranges, but not the splits.

Comment: In reaper you specify how many segments you want to create, and then it will do all calculations. If you have huge partitions then maybe more segments make sense

Comment: To add more to your comment, I found that "nodetool describering" lists the start and end tokens of the ranges for each keyspace on the nodes